# Hibernate session exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I try to do this in my dao:

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    try {

        ProductOrder emp = new ProductOrder();
        session.beginTransaction();
        emp.setProductid(id);
        emp.setSessieid("testsessie");
        emp.setAantal(1);
        session.save(emp);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {

        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }
```

I want to insert something in my database table ProductOrder. When i do this i got an exception.

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported

When i google this exception they say multiple things. Some people say that i have to delete the session.beginTransaction(); But when i delete it i got another exception that the session isn't started.

My db excist of ID, Productid, Aantal(Amount), SessieID(Sessionid). ID is autoincrement so i don't have to fill in this id.

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Did you use PROPAGATION_NESTED propagation?

Comment: How can i use PROPAGATION_NESTED?